# The usage of Python Librosa package for audio - Remove human voice from background noise

Tags: python, audio, audio-player, voice, librosa

I want to remove the human voice from the background noise.
Does anyone know if it is possible using [Librosa Python package](https://github.com/librosa/librosa)?

I am asking this because I saw the usage of librosa only to remove the vocals from accompanying instrumentation.

Does it even work if there are no musical instruments?

Comment: Where did you see that method of separation? Have you tried the same method?

Comment: @AKX I googled how to separate human voice from audio in python. All the results I found were about how to separate human vocals from song. For this reason I was wondering if it works if there is no song but ,instead of it, the environmental noise.

Comment: Does the documentation of librosa say anything about it?

Comment: As I know the functionality of librosa is not enough to separate voice anf background noise. But separation with librosa is not complicated and you may check your samples. Maybe it will work for your type of noise.

Comment: @Antonina Thanks, do you know if there are other libraries to achieve that?

Comment: @Edoardo, I have not seen ready voice-noise separation solutions in python libraries, only some filtration like in librosa.